# Finding the compliment of a logical expression in respect to another logical expression.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

What I would like to do is to find the logical compliment of one expression in respect to another logical expression. If possible, I would like to know if there has been work in this area - I haven't found anything..

So for example. Let $L$ be a logical expression. Now if the "Universe", call it $U$ is the set of all possible logical expressions and if this is the then the compliment of a logical expression is just its dual $U^c$ where $U \cup U^c = 1$ and $U \cap U^c = \emptyset$. The dual of course can be found by negation. So for example letting the expression $E = (x \wedge y)$ we have it's compliment/dual being $E^c = \neg E$ and working out, $E \vee \neg E = 1$ and $E \wedge \neg E = 0$. Note that 1 = True and 0 = False

Now what about the case if we want to find the compliment of one logical expression in respect to another? So, for example, letting $L = (x \wedge y) \vee \neg z$ we want to find what $L \setminus (x \wedge y)$ is. Now I am guessing that we would have to have something such that $(x \wedge y) \vee L \setminus (x \wedge y) = 1$ and that $(x \wedge y) \wedge L\setminus (x \wedge y) = 0$.

I have been experimenting (the point of this post is to see if there is "something" out there that gives proofs of what should happen - or at least address the issue).

I find that if I substitute $\neg (x \wedge y)$ for $(x \wedge y)$ in $L$ calling the substitution $L\setminus (x \wedge y)$, I get the full expression in the case of the disjunction, that is; $(x \wedge y) \vee (\neg(x \wedge y) \vee \neg z) = 1$ Which looks good (whether or not it has any meaning. However when I try the case for the conjunction (again substituting $\neg (x \wedge y)$ for $(x \wedge y)$ in $L$; $(x \wedge y) \wedge (\neg(x \wedge y) \vee \neg z) = x \wedge y \wedge \neg z$ which of course is not always equal to 0 or False!

Note that in the case of a set $S = \{1,2,3\}$ we can easily take $S \{2,3\} = \{1\}$ So I guess ultimately I would be looking for some mechanism that would relate logical expressions to sets and let me modulo out particular expressions.

Thanks for any leads or ideas.

Brian

Comment: I'm not quite sure you want $(x\wedge y)\vee L\setminus (x\wedge y)=1$ if your motivating example is going to be $\mathcal{P}(S)$ for some $S$, as in here the relative complement of $B\in\mathcal{P}(S)$ relative to $A\in\mathcal{P}(S)$ is $A\cap B^\mathsf{c}$.  But then $(A\cap B^\mathsf{c})\cup (A\cap B)$ is not $S$ ($=1$) but $A$.  So I think the axioms you would want are $(x\wedge y)\vee (x\setminus y)=x$ and $(x\wedge y)\wedge (x\setminus y)=0$.  Of course, $x\setminus y=x\wedge \neg y$ gives you exactly what you want (just see that this is the relative complement in a power set).

Comment: A compliment is when you say something nice to someone else. The word you're looking for is *complement*.